# Anylogic: How to block a line by a probability?

Tags: simulation, anylogic

So I'm modelling a production line (simple, with 5 processes which I modelled as Services). I'm simulating for 1 month, and during this one month, my line stops approximately 50 times (due to a machine break down). This stop can last between 3 to 60 min and the avg = 12 min (depending on a triangular probability). How could I implement this to the model? I'm trying to create an event but can't figure out what type of trigger I should use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your services require a resource.  If they are already seizing a resource like labor, that is ok, they can require more than one.  On the resourcePool, there is an area called "Shifts, breaks, failures, maintenance..." Check "Failures/repairs:" and enter your downtime distribution there.

If you want to use a triangular, you need min/MODE/max, not min/AVERAGE/max.  If you really wanted an average of 12 minutes with a minimum of 3 and maximum of 60; then this is not a triangular distribution.  There is no mode that would give you an average of 12.

Average from triangular, where X is the mode:
( 3 + X + 60 ) / 3 = 12

Means X would have to be negative - not possible for there to be a negative delay time for the mode.

Look at using a different distribution.  Exponential is used often for time between failures (or poisson for failures per hour).

Comment: Agree with Amy. When she says "require resources", she means to make your Service blocks use ResourcePool blocks. In the latter, you can define the settings she mentioned.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just inserted a labour and calculated my mode. But how am I able to say that in a month the machine breaks (in average) 50 times? I can only see the possibility to insert the initial time to failure and the time to next failure.

Comment: Your average breakdowns per month will be tied to your time between breakdown.  Assume you have a facility running 24/7, then there would be a breakdown every 14.4 hours (on average) to get you 50 breakdowns per month.  Is the average of your triangular 14.4 hours?  The Poisson is often used when we think of failures per time period.  The Exponential translates that into a time between failures, which AnyLogic would accept.  If you wanted to use the Exponential, instead of the triangular, it would be Exponential( 50 ).